# how can I add the space in log file after execution of particular method , I am using LOG4j

Tags: java

I want a blank line after each transaction of particular method in log file.

```
Ex-
 2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:afterSave:
** Order No :800716 afterSave Started
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:beforeSave:
** Order No :800716 Before Save Started
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:afterSave:
** Order No :800716 afterSave Started
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:processIt:
** Order No :800716 ProcessIt Started
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:completeIt:
** Order No :800716 CompleteIt Started
```

**"              blank line                                               "**

```
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:beforeSave:** Order No :800716 BeforeS ave Started
:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:afterSave:
** Order No :800716 afterSave Started
```

In above Example I want one blank line after completeit method ,I am using log4j.

Comment: And adding line breaks to your desired message does not work?

Comment: put the many "\n" end of "CompleteIt Started".

Comment: I add %n for new line but it gives the blank line after each line in log file, i just want that blank line after completeit method

Comment: after putting \n its gives following on that line:2015-11-26 15:59:04:[INFO]:MOrder:completeIt: